# Microsoft excel concern regarding filter

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I filter one row and get all the rows associated with it from the adjacent column:
for example my spreadsheet looks like

```
A        B
John     Pen
         Mobile
         Headphone
Matt     Book
         Cord
         PC
```

So I want Pen mobile and headphone to display if i filter on John

Comment: How are you doing your filter? Do you have the data in a table?

Comment: easiest way probably is to fill all column A with the names, then apply a conditional formatting which hides (white font colour) names when they're the same as the one above.

Comment: Why did you edited your question and remove those information? previous version was much more better? (you can revert to the previous version by clicking the text showing time of last edit)

Comment: i thought the previous version was a little distorted and hence i edited it. I dotn quite understand the solution that you proposed, If I write John twice and filter, it takes only the first John @mate Juhasz

Comment: Yes. I have the data in 2 columns in excel. @bvaughn

Comment: @MátéJuhász you should hide with ";;;" as a custom Number Format instead because white font is black when printed

Answer (score 3):

Column A must contain the name on **every** row. If you don't do that, not only your filters will not work as expected, but you will very likely mess up your data if you do a sort or delete the row "Matt - Book" (it would appear as if John now have the Cord and PC unless you fix it).

So the solution is to always include all the data that's appropriate for the row.

If you have a lot of data like this, you can find various techniques to fill the blanks faster. I like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20437063/283879 (using select blanks).

### PivotTables

After filling all the blanks, if you need to present your data in a nicer way, PivotTables can help produce a "report" version separately for display and printing. One thing they can do is to put those blanks back.

Try these steps to reproduce your initial spreadsheet after having filled the blanks:

- With your data selected, create a pivot table
- In the "PivotTable Field List", drag column A, then column B in the "Row labels" section.
- In the Design menu under "PivorTable tools" in the menu bar, click "Report Layout" and select "Show in tabular form".
- Also in the Design menu, click "Subtotals" and select "Do not show subtotals"

You should get the following result. Note that unlike your original spreadsheet, you **can** filter the PivotTable on column A, because it knows based on your spreadsheet that the 3 first items belong to Johhn.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I filled the blanks and tried to create a pivot but I am not getting the desired output. Can you please elalborate the steps.

Comment: @kartik Updated with steps and screenshot.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without using the pivot table? because i have other rows and columns also associated with each of the above rows

Comment: I suggest asking a new question. This one was about making the filter work, and now you may have questions on presenting the data differently. Hard to say without understanding more. I'd suggest trying to work with just the spreadsheets without blanks for a while, and if you *really* have issues with it, ask a new question.